# A question is not displayed in the Linked list, even though it is linked

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, linked-questions

This question (A): [How to write the error term in repeated measures ANOVA in R: Error(subject) vs Error(subject/time)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60108) contains a link to this question (B): [Specifying the Error() term in repeated measures ANOVA in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51520), but I do not see question B in the *Linked* list on the question A page and vice versa.

It looks like the SE software does not "get" that these two questions are linked. Why is that? Is it a bug?

In my experience, the *Linked* list has always worked as expected.

Comment: Note that the thread is listed in the *Related* list to the right.

Comment: Yes, but these are two different lists; Related is populated automatically with threads that SE software judges most similar to the given one, whereas Linked is populated with *all* threads that either link to the given one or are linked from it. At least that is what I used to think.

Comment: I wonder if it's because the link is of the form `http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51520`, rather than the more typical `http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/51520/9964` (from the share button) or `http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51520/specifying-the-error-term-in-repeated-measures-anova-in-r` (from the URL bar).

Comment: @Dougal I doubt it. I mostly use this first form (by copying the URL from the address bar and deleting the unnecessary final part of it) and it always worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you probably noticed, the question was asked a long time ago, when the code handling the links had a bug. Editing didn't help much because we only do a full rebuild of the links when a link has been removed. So in order to fix everything up, I've first deleted the link, and then added it back. Now the posts are linked up just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @m0sa!